# Facebook login in spring mvc application

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-mvc

I have an spring mvc web application. But now i want to use facbook login in it. But i dont know how to authenticate spring security in case of facebook login.

I have searched over internet and i have found http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/. but i dont know how to use it. If anyone has sample code. it will be really helpful .

I was looking this article about login with facbook http://dncodes.blogspot.in/2012/06/java-spring-security-authenticate.html#comment-form. But here is a method `doAutoLogin` which is having username and password. But i dont know from where i will get the username and password

Comment: Check out this [link](http://syntx.io/integrating-your-java-spring-mvc-webapp-with-facebook-doing-the-oauth-dance/). It might help. You need to understand the oAuth Dance and setting your application configuration with Facebook.

Comment: That i know but how to authenticate spring security

Comment: check out this one... http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/

Comment: The doc is quite well written actually: http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/. See especially chapteur "4. Signing in with Service Provider Accounts".